# What's the title of the movie where flesh and muscle monsters eat humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

These flesh/muscle like monsters walk very fast and can even run. They can hear noises and are strong. Most establishments' doors and windows are blocked. I remember parts of the movie where

1. There's a dwarf wrestler and he was about to make out with a girl but the girl was eaten when she was grabbed by the window
2. There was another lady trapped in a room and has no escape route and tools she can use so she scratched the window glass till it's broken
3. There are few survivors hiding in the rooftop. One guy was killed by his motorbike. There was a steel inserted in the muffler of the motorbike and when the throttle was twisted it flew and stabbed his head.
4. Another guy from the rooftop went down to get the abandoned baby crying in the car. In the end he didn't successfully rescue it and the baby died and was eaten by the monsters.
5. In the end no one survived. The dwarf wrestler who escaped got killed by his own when the grenade he was supposed to throw at the monsters didn't reach them and instead got inside with him as he was hiding in a metal trash bin. The lady also who scratched the window to escape when fully out of the room got hit by the trash bin cover that flew when the grenade exploded.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: How was the man killed by his motorbike? Accident? Did it become a creature?

Comment: @LogicDictates I watched this movie in 2009 so I think its probably made years before that as it was on CD

Comment: @ArlettaS the muffler of his motorbike was inserted with a rebar steel and when the throttle was twisted it flew and stab his head

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***[Feast II: Sloppy Seconds](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104835/)*** (2008).

> The monsters have made it into a small neighboring town in the middle of nowhere and the locals have to band with the survivors of the bar' slaughter to figure out how to survive.
>
> [image: Image of one of the monsters from "Feast II: Sloppy Seconds" (2008).]

It's the second film in a low-budget horror comedy trilogy about people trying to survive an onslaught of vaguely humanoid, man-eating monsters. It was preceded by *[Feast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0426459/)* (2005), followed by *[Feast III: The Happy Finish](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104836/)* (2009), and features gross-out humour, nudity, and lots of gore.

About six minutes into the film, a Mexican dwarf wrestler named Lightning is having sex with his girlfriend when she's pulled out of the room through a window and killed by one of the monsters.

About an hour and eight minutes in, some people hiding on a rooftop hear the cries of a baby in a car on the street below. A man named Greg swings down and attempts to carry the baby to safety, but a couple of monsters give chase and he ends up throwing the baby in the air in order to distract the monsters and save himself.

About an hour and 25 minutes in, a woman named Honey Pie is trapped in a store and uses the claws of an unconscious monster to scratch a hole through the unbreakable glass on the front door.

About an hour and 31 minutes in, the tailpipe from a motorbike comes loose and flies into Greg's head, piercing his skull.

About an hour and 34 minutes in, Lightning is hiding under a trash can when a man named Hobo drops a lit stick of dynamite right beside him; the explosion launches him across the street, while Honey Pie is hit by a piece of shrapnel from the trash can.

Comment: Thank you for finding the movie! This has  been one of my nightmares as a kid haha I can now rewatch it again♡